# JDBC Postgresql works in Main class only

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, driver

I'm doing a program where I need to manipulate a PostgreSQL database. I downloaded and put the jdbc driver .jar in a lib folder and configured Intellij.

When I use Postgres JDBC driver from the Main.java, everything works fine. Here's an example that prints everything from example table :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Benerator","postgres","newPassword");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from public.example");
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1)+ " " + res.getString(2));}
}
}
```

However, when I write a function that does exactly the same thing in another class than Main, I receive a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on the `Class.forName` line. And of course, every following line has exceptions.

Here is the DBManager.java class :

```
public class DBManager {

    public DBManager(){
    }

    public void printExample(){
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Benerator","postgres","newPassword");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from public.example");
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1)+ " " + res.getString(2));}
    }
}
```

I think it's a newbie question but I had troubles finding the cause of that, any clues?

EDIT : when I surround my code with Try/Catch, everything works just fine

Comment: That sounds unlikely, your problem is probably somewhere different. By the way, you need to register the driver only once.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In a normal Java application you don't need to load the driver at all: it will be automatically loaded by `DriverManager`.

Comment: The error suggests that you did not add the postgresql library to the class path.

Comment: That is obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes it was. I linked the generic duplicate for ClassNotFoundException and one specific to PostgreSQL that demonstrates a solution.

Comment: Then why would it work in a `static` method?

Comment: I added the jdbc postgres .jar in a lib folder of my project and I added that path to my project structure libraries in Intellij but I don't think I added it to the Java classpath. Do you advise to add it in my JDK/JRE lib/ext folder ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Intellij - goto File - Project Structure - Libraries. Make sure you can see the library jdbc if you're running through Intellij
2. If you're running DBManager through a direct Java command then make sure to pass the -cp parameter like `java -cp "somepath/lib/*" mypackage.MainClass`

Comment: Yes, I can actually see it because I added the jar to the libraries of the project in Intellij. And I'm not running the file from cl. I would instance a `DBManager` object in the Main class and then call the `printExample()` method